# ScriptAlias: How to mark DocumentRoot to a target directory

Tags: apache-2.4

I am hosting a git apache server, and I need to trigger a script with ScriptAlias. I was wondering if it was possible to to use ScriptAlias in this fashion, so it is triggered when there is a GET request for the DocumentRoot (eg. `https://domain`) only:

```
ScriptAlias / /path/to/script
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, so my workaround is to use

```
ScriptAlias /git /path/to/script
```

(git is just a placeholder word)
which means my git repo location would be `https://domain/git/foo/bar.git` Is there a way to simplify this to `https://domain/foo/bar.git`?

Much thanks

**Edit: to be more concise**
I want to map the URL `https://domain/` to a cgi script in my filesystem (outside of the DocumentRoot directory). And `ScriptAlias / /path/to/script` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

The `ScriptAlias` directive does two things:

- The first is essentially the same as the `Alias` directive, it maps an URL to file-system path which normally is not a directory in the `DocumentRoot`.
- The second is that it marks that directory as one containing CGI scripts.

When the CGI scripts are already in the `DocumentRoot` you don't need the `Alias` functionality and using a `ScriptAlias` is not necessary, you only need to do the second which is done with :

```
<Location "/">
    SetHandler cgi-script
    Options +ExecCGI
</Location>
```

Comment: Sorry if my post wasn't clear; I want to map the URL `https://domain/` to a cgi script in my filesystem (outside of the DocumentRoot directory). And `ScriptAlias / /path/to/script` doesn't seem to work.